# What should I do when an employee threatens me?

Tags: professionalism, management

My friend is a manager at a store and he fired a man for bringing his own stuff to sell in the store, which is prohibited. He also gave a warning letter to the other guy who helped that man selling his stuff.

Later, my friend found out that the guy who got a warning letter threatened him behind his back. That person posted on his Facebook that he wanted batter my friend. (My friend is not his friend on Facebook, but he got the info from one of his staff.)

What my friend should do in this case? Just let it go, or talk to that man?

Answer (score 6):

If an employee is threatening someone with violence, this is a serious matter. Your friend should not continue to employ someone who threatens violence, but he needs to take measures to ensure safety during the dismissal process.

Your friend should try to get a screenshot of the Facebook post or a transcript to take to authorities or an attorney for advice. If authorities or an attorney are not an option for some reason, your friend should not talk with this employee without a witness present. Letting it go is not really an option. Your friend must be concerned not only with his own safety, but with the safety of customers and other employees.

Comment: this post is rather hard to read (wall of text). Would you mind [edit]ing it into a better shape?

Comment: A documented threat to batter someone is legally actionable. The police should be involved in this matter. And no, the manager should not get near that person. "Looking" for someone to alkit over with- that's thesort of action that provides ammo for the man's defense attorney should the verbal interaction between the manager and him go bad.

Answer (score 6):

Your friend is a manager. They means that there is an general manager, regional manger, owner, or corporation above them. There may even be an HR department. This needs to be escalated within that structure. If the threat was made to his face, then there would be reason to call the authorities directly, but they will need to follow the corporate procedures for documentation and they will need corporate support.

Comment: A written threat even on facebook is actionable in most countries, I'd advise he pursue both paths. Inform the higher ups of the threat and that he is pursuing the legal route to protect himself should the individual attempt to carry out their threat.

Answer (score 5):

Neither. In many countries threatening someone is a crime. Your friend should take a screenshot of the Facebook post (or have it done by the person who reported the threat) and go to the authorities. And of course be extremly careful until the issue is dealt with one way or another.